# tomcat takes wrong context path on deploy

Tags: tomcat, path

I have a problem deploying a war file to tomcat 8.5.24

Whenever I deploy a war file it takes the whole path of the file as context path.

This is how I deploy:

[image: deploy image]

And this is the the result:

[image: result]

If I use 'Deploy directory or WAR file located on server' it works, but I want it to work with the upload function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trying i used a different browser (from IE to google chrome) and it worked...